# Can a user control perform binding when part of a ListView in WinUI?

Tags: c#, binding, user-controls, winui-3, winui

I'm trying to use a UserControl-derived control (UpdateBlockControl) inside the DataTemplate of a ListView, like this:

```xml
    <ListView x:Name="AppsListView">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:AppBase">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <local:UpdateBlockControl ImageSource="{x:Bind ImageSource}" AppName="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Foreground="Orange" Margin="8,0,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ImageSource}" Margin="8,0,0,0" Foreground="LimeGreen"/>
             </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

`UpdateBlockControl` is derived from `UserControl` and I'm trying to bind its properties (ImageSource and AppName) to the model's (AppBase) properties.

You can see me trying to set up these bindings in the first item in the StackPanel. Just to see if the binding works at all, I also bind a couple of TextBlocks to these properties.

The XAML for UserBlockControl is essentially this:

```xml
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text=":-)"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind AppName}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ImageSource}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

When I run the application I see the following:

[image]

So the UserControl properties aren't working correctly it would seem: I get the :-) for the first TextBlock but the second and third TextBlocks are empty. Their equivalents in the ListView *do* work however (see image, above).

**Should I be able to use a user control insisde a DataTemplate like this**? If so, why aren't the bindings working?

Comment: Is this a **WinUI 3** app?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding It is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x:Bind` is `Mode=OneTime` by default. So, once a `DependencyProperty` is initialized inside the `UserControl`, it won't be updated anymore.

You need to add `Mode=OneWay` to `x:Bind` in `UpdateBlockControl`.

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text=":-)" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind AppName, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ImageSource, Mode=OneWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I was also missing INotifyPropertyChanged from the user control. Doesn't seem happy when that's missing.